# I am not utilizing Media Query to make my Angular 2 app responsive. I am just using javascript. Is this a good practice?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want my app to be fully responsive in any screen size. I am not utilizing Media Query and I am just using javascript to make my app responsive with Angular 2: **[style.width], *ngIf="isEmpty"**, etc.. Is this a good practice? Below is a sample of my working code. Thanks.

```
onResize(event: any) {
  this.getResponsive();
}   
getResponsive(){
  var modelQty = this.subCategories.length;
  var margin = 10;
  var fWidth = (screen.width-40) / 10 - margin;
  if(fWidth <= 110)
    fWidth = 110;

  this.frameWidth = fWidth;
  this.frameWidthStr = fWidth + 'px';  //[style.width]="frameWidthStr"
  this.frameHeight = fWidth + 20 + 'px'; 
  this.imageSize = fWidth *.75 + 'px';  //[style.height]="imageSize"

  var totalWidth = (fWidth + margin)*modelQty;
  var tMarginLeft =  (window.innerWidth - totalWidth)/2;

  if(tMarginLeft > 10){
    this.marginLeft = tMarginLeft + 'px';
    this.marginRight = '10px';
  } 
  else {
    this.marginLeft = 10 + 'px';    
    var tWidth = fWidth + 10+2;
    var delta = (window.innerWidth-15) % tWidth;
    let line = window.innerWidth/tWidth;
    line = line - delta / tWidth;
    this.marginRight = 10 + delta/line + 'px'; //[style.margin-right]="marginRight"
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend media queries. I think you may run into issues with browser compatibility. In css it's quite easy to create conditional rules or conditional stylesheets.  May be doable, but I think eventually it will be more effort.

Comment: Ultimately, if there is a standard way to do something, examine the reason for not doing it that way. If the reason is solid, it's a go. If the reason is something like 'more familiar with this' then it's probably not a solid reason.

Comment: The more I make my app progressive, I am using media query through out my app and of course with (window:resize)="onResize($event)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try and shoehorn angular into a custom responsive layout why not work with angular and use a compatible layout library to achieve your requirements.

This one is highly recommended

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout